# Android app to scan a file on multiple antivirus engines using current definitions

Tags: gratis, android, security, antivirus, malware

I am looking for a [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) [android](/questions/tagged/android) app that will scan a file on multiple [antivirus](/questions/tagged/antivirus) engines ***using current definitions***.

What I've tried:

- [VirusTotal by VIRUSTOTAL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.virustotal) - Only scans installed apps
- [VirusTotal Mobile by Funnycat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funnycat.virustotal) - Cannot rescan using current definitions
- [VirusTotal Uplink by Frizzware](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.frizzware.virustotaluplink) - Cannot rescan using current definitions

Not tried, but according to reviews, will not meet requirements:

- [VirusTotal Uploader by Vitaly Novitsky](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by.nvs.vtuploader) - According to reviews, cannot rescan using current definitions

I am open to recommendations that use any service that scans using multiple antivirus/malware engines (using VirusTotal is definitely ***not*** a requirement).

Comment: What are current definitions?

Comment: @アレックス  Current definitions are the latest definitions available for each antivirus scanning engine.  By default, VirusTotal just shows results using the (typically outdated) definitions available when the file was first scanned.  On their website, you can force VirusTotal to rescan using the current definitions; I have not found an Android app that will force a VirusTotal rescan.  Note that using VirusTotal is definitely not a requirement for answers to this question.

Comment: But what does "definition" mean in this context?

Comment: @アレックス Virus definitions are largely what antivirus tools use to determine if a file contains a virus.  This is commonly coupled with heuristic evaluations and other types of testing.

Comment: I wonder, how do those applications work, do they send files to virustotal each time they're scanning the files on a drvice? Or do they work offline somehow?

Comment: @アレックス They do not work offline.  They must transfer the file, or at least a hash of it, to a server.

Comment: I think I'll build the app. And then let you know. But I wonder, how does the default virustotal android app work without asking me for the ApiKey?  I think other apps communicating with curatorial do as well -- they don't require my ApiKey. Do they contain the original developer's apikey hardcoded?

Comment: @アレックス That sounds great!  Thanks!  I do not know the answers to your questions.  Perhaps someone else does.

Comment: @アレックス Any success in building the app?

Comment: no, I haven't worked on it.